# ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row when adding root in a tree structure

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have created a database with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE progettoschemas.categories (
  id DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  fatherid DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (fatherid) REFERENCES progettoschemas.categories(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

because I want a tree structure where an element is related to its father id. Now the problem is that I'd like the root to have parameters like: id=1 name=root fatherid=0 (the fatherid=0 is important and I prefer not to change it cause if I do I will have to modify a lot of my code) but obviously mysql doesn't allow me to do it because there is no reference with that 0 as fatherid. Is there a way to solve my problem mantaining the parameters I want or I have to modify them in some ways?

Comment: Either remove the foreign key constraint (you shouldn't) or make the column nullable and save `NULL` in that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any effective solution without modifying my db structure, so I was forced to change my db to:

```
CREATE TABLE progettoschemas.categories (
  id DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  fatherid DOUBLE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (fatherid) REFERENCES progettoschemas.categories(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

and added a row called root with id=0 and fatherid=null